# Right use of packages in android project

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, fragment

I am working on a project with a lot of classes and I want to correctly structure them in packages. I am concerned by one thing:

The activity live cycle is modified as **protected** and has a java rule:

**The subclass can see the protected  member only through inheritance**

I am also using **fragments**, so my questions are:

1. Can I structure the activitys and fragments in different packages
   without unwanted "side effects"?
2. If so, what's the right way do define structure of packages - for example is the right way to put "model data" in different packages or not, and what about the data from the server for example like Parse.com?

Comment: Yes you can. :) No significant side effects of managing classes using packages.

Comment: @kopikaokao your answer based on personal experience? can you answer also the last part?

Comment: @Kagemusha thanks for editing :)

Comment: It is based on my personal experience and also the main usage of java package is to prevent naming conflicts, to control access, to make searching/locating and usage of classes, interfaces, enumerations and annotations easier, etc. as quoted in this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_packages.htm). 
As for last question, there is no finite answer for it. It depends on your preferences.

Comment: @kopikaokao thanks :)

Comment: if i got your point about `protected` you don't have to worry, because you are not supposed to call any of the activity/fragment life cycle methods, this is handled by the OS (android). if that what you mean...

Comment: @Yazan I also thought so but wasn't totaly sure. thanks for making it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages in Java is a mechanism to encapsulate a group of classes, interfaces and sub packages. Many implementations of Java use a hierarchical file system to manage source and class files. It is easy to organize class files into packages.

1. Can I structure the activitys and fragments in different packages
   without unwanted "side effects"?

   **Yes, you can. It doest have any side effects. Instead it will be in organized way and easy for you to search and maintain.**
2. If so, what's the right way do define structure of packages - for
   example is the right way to put "model data" in different packages
   or not, and what about the data from the server for example like
   Parse.com?

   **Yes, you should make different packages for MODEL , CONTROLLER , VIEWS etc**

We need packages because

1. Abstraction
2. Protection
3. Convenience
4. Name Space Control
5. Reusability

Check [this](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~kjg/cs102/Notes/Packages/) for more decription.